# Unity Dependency Injection's version of WhatDoIHave

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I was wondering if Unity has something similar to StructureMap's WhatDoIHave(). I've found WhatDoIHave() in StructureMap to be very helpful when wiring in dependencies in my container, and am now forced to use Unity for one of my projects. Does Unity provide anything similar? I couldn't find anything on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. There is no such thing in Unity.

Comment: Darn. Thanks, @Steven.

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) contains a list of containers that have some sort of 'what do I have' kind of feature. From the most popular libraries, only Simple Injector, StructureMap and Castle Windsor have such a feature.